# jTable Not Displaying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-jtable

I'm trying to build a website including jQuery and jTable. As such, I've been trying to use the example jTable scripts that the website provides, but I can't seem to get any input returned. The file paths all work, and I check to make sure jQuery was loaded (it was). I'm really not sure what I'm doing wrong, if anything. Thanks!

jTable file:

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="JQueryUI/css/smoothness/jquery-ui-1.8.21.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<link href="jtable/themes/standard/blue/jtable_blue.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jtable/jquery.jtable.js"></script>
</head>
<title>Under Construction</title>
Hello World
<div id="PersonTableContainer"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable({
           title: 'Table of people',
            actions: {
    listAction: 'PersonList.php'
    createAction: 'CreatePerson.php'
    updateAction: 'UpdatePerson.php'
    deleteAction: 'DeletePerson.php'
        },
        fields: {
            PersonId: {
                key: true,
                create: false,
                edit: false,
                list: false
            },
            Name: {
                title: 'Author Name',
                width: '40%'
            },
            Age: {
                title: 'Age',
                width: '20%'
    },
            RecordDate: {
                title: 'Record date',
                width: '30%',
                type: 'date',
                create: false,
                edit: false
            }
        }
    });

    $('#PersonTableContainer').jtable('load');
});
```

PersonList.php

```
<?php
$link = new mysqli("localhost", "user", "pass", "people");

$query = "SELECT * FROM people";
$results = mysqli_query($link, $query);
$rows = array();
while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results))
{
    $rows[] = $row;
}
$jTableResult = array();
$jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
$jTableResult['Records'] = $rows;
print json_encode($jTableResult);
}
?>
```

PersonList.php returns the proper output in terminal, it just doesn't seem to display anything in the website/jTable.

Comment: Can you confirm that the AJAX request is completing successfully via your console?

Comment: @Colin - I'm not sure I understand what you're asking. How would I confirm that?

Comment: I'm not very familiar with jTable, but I assume it makes an AJAX request to your .php files. One thing to check would be that you're getting the expected results back from that call. Your browser's console should have a "Network" (or something similar) tab that will display the AJAX request when it's made. You can inspect what parameters were sent and, of course, what data (if any) was returned. Might be good to confirm all is working properly there.

Answer (score 0):

Try below and let me know if it works, I don't have a lot of experience with it but I even made a custom search function for it if you need it.

I use a single actions file and I use $_REQUEST for it though, not different files like you do.

```
//Get records from database
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM people;");

//Add all records to an array
$rows = array();
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
{
$rows[] = $row;
}

//Return result to jTable
$jTableResult = array();
$jTableResult['Result'] = "OK";
$jTableResult['Records'] = $rows;
print json_encode($jTableResult);
```

Answer (score 0):

to debug this I'd start with three angles:
1. look at the AJAX response in developer tools.  In Chrome that is on the Network tab, filtering by XHR.  First verify that the AJAX call is being made and look at the response.
2. verify that the AJAX response is getting into the jtable context.  Just add these lines under your fields attribute:

```
fields: {
    ...
},
recordsLoaded: function(event, data) {
    console.log(data);
}
```

3. in the browser console expand this console.log object and look at the array items.  jtable is case sensitive so the resulting parameters must have the same spelling and capitalization.  its usually pretty easy to just change the field names in the jtable description to match the db field names.